# Nginx reverse folder location to external website

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

As a Nginx newbie i am trying to get a reverse proxy working to an external domain. Later on I will need to port to an internal domain. When trying to reverse proxy to an external domain i seem to hit a wall and the response is a 404 cannot be found.

The goal is when i try to access http://localhost/example the reverse proxy serves www.example.com.

This is my config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /example/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://www.example.com/;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Any hint what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When speaking about http, webserver detects which of configured servers was requested by checking `Host` header. In you case, you tell nginx to proxy requests to another server, but instruct it to pass original `Host` header to that server. Obviously, there is no configuration on remote server, which could accept request with that domain. So it responds you with `404`.

To make it work, just change header to `proxy_set_header Host www.example.com;` where instead of `www.example.com` you should use same host as in `proxy_pass` directive. (or same variable)

Comment: Is this the correct block?

    location /example/ {
        proxy_set_header Host www.example.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass h*ttp://www.example.com;
    }

When i try this i get indeed a different error but now a <title>500 - Internal Server Error</title>

Comment: @Marco proxy_pass should contain url with protocol and uri. So that was okay in your first example `proxy_pass http://example.com/;`